# How to use IF logic to classify as Income or Debt

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to classify each row as either an Income or Debt based on if it is a positive or negative number.

This is what I have:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3ctz.png
This is my current formula:
=IFS(G2 <= (-1), "Debts", G2 >= (0),"Income")

When I apply the formula to the column it does not input the correct output.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your values seem to be formated as TEXT

Comment: Try wrapping G2 in `VALUE()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is related to text format numbers as is described in comments. Using `Value` will work but I'm a fan of using the shorter syntax of `+0` (aka *my RSVP to wedding invitations*....).

```
=If(G2+0>=0,"Income","Debt")
```

Also, if you have Excel spill ranges and want to have the `Type` column auto-populate all values in the column, you could set this formula in cell `H2`

```
=filter(if(G2:G999999+0>0,"Income","Debt"),not(ISBLANK(G2:G999999)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `=IF(G2<=0, "Debt", "Income")`